# Meteor keydown/keyup events outside input

Tags: meteor

After reading this thread:
[Keypress events stopped working outside of "input" elements in Meteor after update to 0.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618262/keypress-events-stopped-working-outside-of-input-elements-in-meteor-after-upda)

I understand that keydown/keyup events are not possible unless you add it to $(document).on('keyup')..... inside the Rendered callback.

But that thread is over 2 years old. Is this still the case? Is there still no "Meteor Way" of adding a keyup/keydown event outside input/contenteditable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a keyup event for the whole page on page load, the "meteor way" is to use `Meteor.startup`:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  $(document).on('keyup', function (e) {...});
}
```

Comment: That's great, but what if I want to add a key event on a single template ONLY and allow key events to occur even when not focused on an input/editable elements?

Comment: That is not possible. See here: http://api.jquery.com/keydown/ "The keydown event is sent to an element when the user first presses a key on the keyboard. It can be attached to any element, but the event is only sent to the element that has the focus. Focusable elements can vary between browsers, but form elements can always get focus so are reasonable candidates for this event type."

Answer (score 14):

The answer to your question is yes, it can still be done that way. You can still make key event listeners for single templates by adding the event listener in the `onCreated` or `onRendered` methods like so:

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(() => {
    $(document).on('keyup', (e) => {
        console.log('A key has come up.');
    });
});
```

You do not have to do it in `Meteor.startup` as suggested by the currently accepted answer.

To destroy the event so that it doesn't persist when no longer within this template:

```
Template.myTemplate.onDestroyed(() => {
    $(document).off('keyup');
});
```

Comment: Except for that the event is still there after the template is destroyed

Comment: Sure, but that can be cleaned up when the template is destroyed.

Comment: But since you brought it up, I added that here.

Comment: I agree this should be the accepted answer; although the cleanup function is incorrect - it should be `onDestroyed`